# Is this matrix algebra move correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I’ve started a linear algebra class and I have no idea if this equation is correct, suppose $A$ and $B$ are square matrices with $n$ rows, and suppose $x$ is a vector with $n$ elements. Given:

If it is true that $Ax=Bx$, is it always the case that
$A=B?$

Could you explain why this is True or False?

Comment: With questions like these, it's worth trying examples to build evidence one way or the other.  A hint: think about $x=(1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: he is free to ask whatever he wants, you are only bothering him with you comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ Ax= Bx $ for every vector $x$ then they are the same, since $A e_i = Be_i$

the i'th columns are equal for every i, where $e_i$ is the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$

If only for a single value of $x$, $Ax=Bx$, then they are not necessarily equal. Take
$ A = \begin {bmatrix} 1 -1 \\ 1 -1 \end{bmatrix}$, $B = 2 * A$, and $x = [1, 1]^t$,
Then $Ax=Bx=[0,0]$.